# Runtime parameters in SQL string don't get their values ExecuteNonQuery fails with no runtime errors

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, stringbuilder

The following code does not even throw an exception and the parameters @p1, @p2 and @p3 don't get have their runtime values: `ExecuteNonQuery` return zero

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the development server, run the profiler to see what is actually be passed to the SQL Server engine.

Also, put some debug lines in the VB.NET code.  I am sure something is off.

PS:  Show us the final query in text format.  All the string appends makes it more confusing to read.

These statements can be removed.

```
DECLARE @cur_date_time datetime;  
SELECT @cur_date_time = getdate();
```

Just change first line to second version.

```
AND d.DateModified >= @cur_date_time  
AND d.DateModified >= getdate()
```

I would use the newer syntax for joins.  Please note, after making the inline getdate() change, I noticed you have tables a, b, and c in a cross join relationship.  IE - They are not joined on keys.  Is this what you really want.

```
INSERT INTO 
    aic_global_change_xref(ChangeTableGUID, ChangeRecordGUID, GlobalChangeGUID)  
SELECT  
    a.GUID as ChangeTableGUID, 
    d.GUID as ChangeRecordGUID, 
    b.GUID as GlobalChangeGUID  
FROM  
    aic_change_table a
    aic_global_change b
    aic_rationale c 
LEFT JOIN
    aic_obs_set_obs_set_obs_item_xref_chg d on c.GUID = d.RationaleGUID 
LEFT JOIN
    aic_obs_set e ON d.ParentObsSetGUID = e.GUID  
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.aic_obs_set f ON d.ChildObsSetGUID = f.GUID  

WHERE 
  f.GUID = @p1 and 
  d.ParentObsSetGUID = @p2 and
  c.RationaleText = @p3 and 
  d.DateModified >= getdate()  and 
  a.ChangeTableName = 'aic_obs_set_obs_set_obs_item_xref_chg' and
  b.GlobalChangeCode = 'EDITS';
```

I would take the code I gave you, place it into SSMS and define @p1, @p2, and @p3.  See what you are getting back as results.

I changed everything to left joins so that data was not being dropped out of the equation.  Since I have no idea about your business logic and do not have your dataset, the rest of the work is up to you.

Good luck!

Comment: just added the run time sql...i know this is really hard to read...the whole app is just like this...

Comment: does anything jump out as off?

Comment: Run the code in SSMS until you have the results you want.  The rewrite I did makes things cleaner.  Removed the IN clause since you have only one variable.  A cross join is a cross product of the records.  10 records in a, b, & c = 10x10x10 = 1K.  I made all the joins left so that data is not eliminated from the results.  Change this back according to your business requirements.